# Bibliography first citation is indented

Tags: bibliographies

I started using LaTeX to write my assignments and also my thesis. Today I came up with a problem (for me at least it kind of is). When I'm writing

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{assignment}
```

to print the references of the assignment (its class is article) what comes up is the following:
[image]

Before printing the references what I have is just a section with a paragraph and a pagebreak to print the references in a separate page.

```
\section{Summary}
{bla bla bla}
\pagebreak
```

Why is the first reference indented and the others not? To be honest the rest of the document starts at the same position as the first reference. So I want all of them to be like the first one. How do I achieve that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Is the indentation still occuring, if you remove the `\pagebreak`-command? The problem could be narrowed down, if you could set up a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem; please, try and present a MWE.

Comment: I'm trying to create a MWE as we speak. The think is that if I remove the main body (all the text) from the article and just write something to test the references appear correct so I can't easily reproduce the problem myself. Will provide more information as soon as possible.

Comment: I think that my problem appears when I use

    /cite{...}

Are there any escape characters that I should avoid using in the position of the dots?

Comment: @gkaran89 No, `\cite{}` is pretty straightforward and does not require any further escaping. An improperly formatted BibTeX-entry could also cause be the culprit, though. Some digits in your DOI-fields seem a bit off in the picture. Try a very basic .bib-file with as little information as possible.

Comment: So the problem was in my bib file. In some BibTeX entries I had an underscore character on the note field (not entirely my fault because I copy pasted the BibTeX entries from springerlink). Once I used a backslash to escape the underscore character everything worked out. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Too localised based on that comment.